# Query speed improvements

Tags: mysql, tuning

Referencing:

`CREATE TABLE words (
  word_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  word varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (word)
)`

`CREATE TABLE synonyms (
  source_index int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  destination_index int(10) unsigned NOT NULL
)`

Querying:

`SELECT w.word, z.word
 FROM words w
 INNER JOIN synonyms y
  ON w.word_id=y.source_index
  INNER JOIN words z
  ON z.word_id=y.destination_index
 WHERE w.word='kind'`

The problem is a query on a table with less than 120,000 entries takes 400+ seconds. I was hoping this would be more efficient than having a second table with a similar word list for the synonyms, but so far it is proving otherwise. I have no qualms with keeping synonyms a separate word table as it isn't quite a duplicate of words. I am not finding anything applicable on tuning such queries for lower time online. Is there a way to  tune this for reasonable speed (<100 msec) or am I better off without the 'split self reference'?

Comment: Do you have any indexes on the tables? And what is your DBMS (MySQL, Oracle, Postgres, DB2, SQL Server, ...)?

Comment: Added `mysql` tag based on the usage of `int(10)`

Comment: @ypercube: At the time, I did no, which I should have caught. I am adding them now, which should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you have only added one index on `words` for `word`. Therefore your query will right now result in at least one [full table scan](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/sql-full-table-scan/) for both `words` and `synonyms`, probably even more - that might depend on your DBMS and it's query optimizer's abilities.

Try adding [an index](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/what-is-an-index/) on `words` for `word_id` and on `synonyms` for at least `source_index`. This way your query will use the index and not do a full table scan.

You could probably improve on that by using [covering indeces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62137/what-is-a-covered-index), e.g. `(word_id, word)` on `words` and `(source_index, destination_index)` on `synonyms`.

Comment: I am working on implementing this, but I should have realized this was what I was missing... Thank you for pointing it out!